# How to fix "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'storage'" error in python2.7

Tags: python-2.7, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In apache beam pipeline, I am taking input from cloud storage and trying to write it in biqguery table. But during the execution of pipeline getting this error. "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'storage'"

```
def run(argv=None):
    with open('gl_ledgers.json') as json_file:
        schema = json.load(json_file)
    schema = json.dumps(schema)
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--input',
                        dest='input',
                        default='gs://bucket_name/poc/table_name/2019-04-12/2019-04-12 13:47:03.219000_file_name.csv',
                        help='Input file to process.')
    parser.add_argument('--output',
                        dest='output',
                        required=False,
                        default="path to bigquery table",
                        help='Output file to write results to.')
    known_args, pipeline_args = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(pipeline_args)
    pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True
    p = beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options)
    (p
     | 'read' >> ReadFromText(known_args.input)
     # | 'Format to json' >> (beam.ParDo(self.format_output_json))
     | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(known_args.output, schema=schema)
     )

    result = p.run()
    result.wait_until_finish()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

````
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 773, in run
    self._load_main_session(self.local_staging_directory)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 489, in _load_main_session
    pickler.load_session(session_file)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 269, in load_session
    return dill.load_session(file_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 410, in load_session
    module = unpickler.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 864, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1139, in load_reduce
    value = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 828, in _import_module
    return getattr(__import__(module, None, None, [obj]), obj)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'storage'```
````

Comment: Can you please show your imports and what libs you've installed?

Answer (score 2):

This is probably related to `pipeline_options.view_as(SetupOptions).save_main_session = True`. Do you need that line?

Try removing that and see if it fixes the problem. It is likely that one of your imports can not be pickled. Without imports I can't help you debug further. You could also try moving your imports into the run function.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53860066/gitlab-ci-runner-cant-import-google-cloud-in-python), in which case the problem would be that `google-cloud-storage` needs to be installed, not `google-cloud`.